# how to do map dependencies with code maps using VS code on ubuntu?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I encountered this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2019, and I was thinking to follow it to generate code maps for my c++ code running on ubuntu vs code of version 1.61.2. Somehow I can not even find the tool menu and the solution explorer. I managed to install the solution explorer as my VS code extension. But I still do not know how to get started. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that the dependency maps are only available in Visual Studio and not in VSCode, which are two separate things